# JQuery onClick and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys so I'm using this simple function to flip card and I'm having some issues.
This is the function:

```
function flipIt() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

Now when I call it directly in html like this:

```
<div class="card" onclick="flipIt()">
```

it works well but when i try to call it directly in my JS file it doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
$('.card').onclick(flipIt());
```

and this:

```
$('.card').on(click, function(){
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

Here is mine JSBin so you can see my whole code.

Comment: It's `$('.card').click(flipIt);`

Comment: jQuery does not have onclick and you are calling the function. Second one fails because you do not have click in quotes.  And if it still is not working, that is because you are adding the events before the elements are loaded so you need to use event delegation. `$('.card').click(flipIt);` or `$(".card").on("click", flipIt);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event(`click`) should be in quotes.

```
$('.card').on('click', function() {
  $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

You can actually refer to the `card` that was clicked using `this`.

```
$('.card').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```